# Method call in constructor does not work, made method final and still does not work

Tags: java, constructor

I am tring to set my objects state in my constructor. I call the `setState` method.
This keeps giving me `null`. I read that you can't call methods that can be overridden in a constructor, so I figured that was why. I made the `setState` method final and still see the issue.

Is it ok to just do `myState = x;` in the constructor instead of calling `setState(x)`?

Also any thoughts why the call to `setState` in the constructor does not work even if the method is final?

One more point is that the class that all this is done in is abstract, not sure if that makes any difference.

Language is Java.

I am not sure about posting code, my company is sensitive to that. Don't want to get in trouble with my employer.

I will post some generic code

```
public abstract class Abc

public Abc()
{
setState(uninit);
}

public final void setState(state s)
{
myState = s;
}
```

This does not work, if I change the line

```
setState(uninit);
```

to

```
myState = uninit;
```

it works, but I am not sure this is a good idea, because I have a setter for the state.

Comment: Some code and perhaps a tag specifying the language might be useful to get some help

Comment: `myState = x;` is perfectly legitimate in a constructor.

Comment: What's the error the compiler gives you?

Comment: what do you mean by "keep giving you null"? As far as posting code goes, could you come up with similar code, stripped down to just the part to which you are referring?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I will go with myState = uninit.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you forgot to call the super constructor in the sub-class constructor.

```
super();
```

It is something like

```
public class sub_abc extends abc}

 public sub_abc(){
  super();
  ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your actual code is but I don't find the parameter name in the formal parameter list of the `setState()` method.

```
public abstract class abc
{
    public abc()
    {
        setState(uninit);
    }

    public final void setState(state s)  //Seems to be something like this.
    {
        myState = s;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you must follow the Java naming-conventions. Accordingly your class name `abc` should be replaced as `Abc` and so on.

Comment: uninit, is a state of an enum. Stands for uninitialized. Tring to set the state to uninitialized.

Comment: As for Null, When I print out the state, I see null not an actual state, therefore the setState never gets called correctly.

Comment: Lion, you are correct. I was tring to be quick, sorry. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I usually initialize my class variables in the constructor like that. The getters and setters are usually only for other classes to use, so I see no reason why you cannot just use myState = uninit;

```
public abstract class abc {
    private State uninit;

    public abc()
    {
        myState = uninit;
    }

    public final void setState(State newState) 
    {
        myState = newState;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you directly copy from my answer or so?

Comment: Actually I probably did copy yours by mistake to start out. That wasn't my intention. I was just reviewing it to see what you were talking about. I did change the constructor though and the case of the State data type.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `myState = x;` in the constructor has the exact same effect as calling `setState(uninit);`; at least as far as I can imagine your original code to be. In that case then, the error must be somewhere else. Perhaps you are calling `setState` again? Or something else that is different between the two tests. I would put a breakpoint in the constructor and step through the code.

There is nothing here that your company can object to as being sensitive. If it makes you more comfortable, use [an online compiler such as ideone](http://ideone.com/)